# Can't see lowercase "g" in Unity Hud

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, unity-dash, ccsm

UPDATE: The issue has been fixed after restarting my PC.

After reinstalling Ubuntu for the billionth time [because I can], I have come across a very odd issue. I can type the letter "g" in Unity Dash, but it doesn't show. The uppercase version "G" shows.

I have done a bit of customization with CCSM so it's probably something there. Most screens are not shown, that is because I know I haven't changed anything in them.

Any ideas? [Screenshots of the issue in the Unity Dash are in a Imgur album here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByoUZ.jpg).

[Screenshots of my CCSM changes are in a Imgur album here](https://imgur.com/a/yIyYc).

Comment: Well, that's intresting...

Comment: Hasn't happened in any other Ubuntu installs. I'll dump my apt sources and installed packages list some time tomorrow and I'm hoping a reboot fixes the issue. Could be something lubuntu, it has been problematic but I doubt it. The screenshots haven't been edited/gimped with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix: restarting the PC.

I don't know why I couldn't see the letter "g" before, but I can now.